# Where is rake 10.0.4 coming from?

Tags: rubygems, rake, rvm

When I run `rake test` on version 10.0.4 I get big unneeded stack traces. According to some searching, upgrading to rake 10.1.0 fixes the issue. I tried installing rake 10.1.0 but my system is still executing 10.0.4 when I `rake test`. I tried to get rid of it; this is what happens.

```
$ gem list | grep rake:
    rake (10.1.0, 10.0.4)

$ gem uninstall rake -v=10.0.4
    INFO:  gem "rake" is not installed

$ rake -V
    rake, version 10.0.4
```

Other vitals: OS X 10.8.4, JRuby 1.7.4, Rails 3.2.13

How can I get 10.0.4 off my system, and why doesn't `gem uninstall` see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bundle exec rake, which will use the rake version specified in your gem file as this can change from project to project.

Comment: Thanks, that enabled me to run 10.1.0 once I specified that in my Gemfile - do you have any suggestions as to why 10.0.4 was/is still hanging around?

Answer (score 3):

Use `gem list -d rake` to see full paths to gems, most likely the `10.0.4` `rake` is installed in `@global` gemset, use:

```
rvm @global do gem uninstall rake -ax
```

Comment: This one helped me solve a long time problem of mine on trying to uninstall what seems to be an "uninstallable rake gem"! Thanks!